# Transactions and Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, transactions, eloquent, laravel-5

I want to use transactions in my laravel application. However, I struggle to use them with Eloquent.

```
$user = $this -> auth -> user();

DB::transaction(function()
{
    $stores_amount = $user -> stores() -> count(); #Error
});
```

I get an "Undefined variable: user" error. What is my problem and how can I use SELECT statements in Eloquent with transactions correctly?

Comment: Most likely you have a scoping problem - the variable $user is not visible within the function scope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$user` isn't in scope inside your callback

```
$user = $this->auth->user();

DB::transaction(function() use ($user) {
    $stores_amount = $user->stores()->count();
});
```

**EDIT**

`$stores_amount` is only scoped inside of the callback. If you need to get the `$stores_amount` value out of the transaction, then you can declare it and scope it into the callback as well, but by reference:

```
$user = $this->auth->user();
$stores_amount = 0;
DB::transaction(function() use ($user, &$stores_amount) {
    $stores_amount = $user->stores()->count();
});
```

Comment: Wow, thanks. That's basically what I wantend. One last thing: It seems I have the same problem with the "$stores_amount" variable. How can I use it out of the transaction-function?